# How can I use parameters/arguments for my callback function in array_map()?

Tags: php, callback, anonymous-function, array-map

I'm using this code to get an array from a csv file:

```
array_map('str_getcsv', 'file.csv')
```

But how do I set delimeter for `str_getcsv()` when using it in array_map function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need to attach additional parameters to a function that requires a callable the easiest way it to just pass in a wrapper function with your parameters pre-defined

```
$array = array_map(function($d) {
    return str_getcsv($d, "\t");
}, file("file.csv"));
```

Alternatively you can pass in parameters using the [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) syntax with the closure.

```
$delimiter = "|";
$array = array_map(function($d) use ($delimiter) {
    return str_getcsv($d, $delimiter);
}, file("file.csv"));
```

Another fun thing that can be done with this technique is create a function that returns functions with predefined values built in.

```
function getDelimitedStringParser($delimiter, $enclosure, $escapeChar){
    return function ($str) use ($delimiter, $enclosure, $escapeChar) {
        return str_getcsv($str, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escapeChar);
    };
}

$fileData = array_map("trim", file("myfile.csv"));
$csv = array_map(getDelimitedStringParser(",", '"', "\\"), $fileData);
```

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for the facelift :)